# match condition not working on mongoose populate

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using `batch_id` to dip in `CoursePurchaseModel` and using `user_id` I am populating to `userModel` on condition of `startDate` and `endDate` but I am getting `user_id` null every time. I am new to Mongoose. Am I missing something?

[image: CoursePurchaseModel]
[image: UserModel]

```js
getUsersByBatchIdAccordingDate: async (startDate, endDate, batch_id) => {

    let findifUsers = await module.exports.getUsersAccordingDate(startDate, endDate);
    if (findifUsers.length == 0) {
        return Error("No users found");
    }

    let userData = await CoursePurchasedModel.find({ batch_id: batch_id })
        .populate({
            path:'user_id',
            model:'User',
            match: { createdAt: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } },
            select: 'name email gender number address state pincode unique_code referedBy creditEarned refer_id LastAppOpenedTime createdAt -_id'
        }).exec();

    let userArray = [];
    for (let data of userData) {
        let newVideoObject = { ...data.user_id.toObject() }
        userArray.push(newVideoObject);
    }
    return userArray;
}
```

Comment: I removed match and straight awayused condition createdAt: { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } and it worked. How ?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about `aggregation`. You can match the values from other document's fields using `aggregation`. It returns as the populated field. If you don't need to match, populate already works as you wish. But for matching/filtering values, aggregation needs to be used.

```
  let userData =  await CoursePurchasedModel.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "userModel",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "userModelTable",
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
    {
      "userModelTable.createdAt": { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate } 
    },
    {
      batch_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(batch_id)
    }
    ]
  },
])
```

In the result, `UserModel` is populated as `userModelTable`. Also, it is already matched by the `createdAt` value.

I hope, it is useful for you.

Comment: using your way of aggregate is giving me empty array in return

Comment: try to write aggregate without match condition. If it gives you all the values, then problem at match conditions. But it doesn't look like there's a problem. Did you change "from" value in $lookup. It needs to be your schemas name. as "usermodels". If it's not problem also, then try to remove conditions in $match one to one. Because problem is on one of them probably. Probably, you didn't change from value in $lookup. If it doesn't solve your problem, write here please

Comment: I have not changed anything using your aggerate function. Removing condition inside $match or also removing $match still i am getting empty array... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ok. try to change this line from: "userModel". You need to write here the document name in mongoDb. It always uses lowercases. Can be as usermodels because of it has lowercases and pulural. Check it from your mongoDb compass and write the "from" in $lookup. This solves your problem.

Comment: i solved the issue using for let.  I am learning aggregation function now, Will implement your given solution and let you know.

Comment: Well done friend. I know that the problem about aggregation is so simple. After learning basically, you are gonna solve it easily.. Good luck